# How do you scale an SVG inside a :before pseudo Element

Tags: css, svg

I have a class that puts an SVG-icon inside a before element. I want to scale this SVG because at the moment it still appears to big. However nothing I tried worked.

```
.svg-icon:before {
    content: url('icons/svg-icon.svg');
    position: relative;
    /* none of these work*/
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

So what can I do to adjust the SVG-size?

Edit: I seem to be able to adjust it, when I set `position: inline-block`. However, when I do that, I can't use `top` and `bottom`, which I need.

Solutions:
@I haz kode and @NiZa had the right idea. This way it works:

```
.svg-icon:before {
    content: "";
    background: url('icons/svg-icon.svg') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Why not move the SVG to `background` instead of `content`?

Comment: And keep the content with empty string ('') as value

Comment: The problem is probably your SVG. For example, does it have hard-wired `width` and `height` values?  Please post it (or a sample).

Comment: At first, setting content: "" and background: url('icons/svg-icon.svg') didn't work for me, so I thought that would be the wrong way to go, but I tried it again after you mentioned it and fiddled around a bit. Now it works. See edit in post. Thank you! :)